# Terraform: Module's output variable to azure-pipelines.yml file

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-storage

I am using Terraform Modules for storage account and once storage account is created I want to use output variable for the access key

```
 output "storage_account_primary_access_key" {
  value = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_access_key
}
```

Further in my azure-pipelines.yml, I am using "az command" as below

```
 az storage blob upload-batch -s drop -d \$web --account-name "" --account-key ""
```

How can I use Module's output variable in the YML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [output](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output) command. For example:

```
terraform output storage_account_primary_access_key
```

So you may do something like this:

```
az storage blob upload-batch -s drop -d $web \
 --account-name "" \
 --account-key "$(terraform output -raw storage_account_primary_access_key)"
```

You could also assign it to variable, that you can use throughout your popeline. Something along these lines.

```
- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ACCESS_KEY]$(terraform output -raw storage_account_primary_access_key)"
```

Comment: I get below error 
│ 
│ Warning: No outputs found  The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs
│ are empty. Please define an output in your configuration with the `output`
│ keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become available. If you are
│ using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You
│ can use the `terraform console` command to assist.

Comment: well as it stands this is the defacto way to get output variables from terraform. You can also see this in the offical docs. If it doesnt work, it may be due to something that you dont show here. I suggest showing your pipeline.yaml

Comment: How to use terraform output command to get output's object child value? I have complex output like this: storage_account { "primary_access_key" = "123" "another_key" = "321" }